# Spring Web Application - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, web

I would like to ask you for an advice what could be wrong with my easy tutorial example of spring web applications.

I am trying to reach website on this URL:

```
http://localhost:8084/SpringTutorial/hello
```

As a response to this URL I get HTTP 404 - Resource not available - from apache tomcat server.

Image of project folder structure is at the bottom of this article.

Here is the code:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <display-name>SpringTutorial</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>

            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scanning for anotation base classes (controllers) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" /> 
    <!-- Using anotation based classes (controllers) -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframeúwork.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.controllers;

import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sayHello(){
        ModelAndView hello = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        hello.addObject("message", "Welcome at first Spring web application");
        return hello;
    }        
}
```

**HelloPage.jsp**
Displaying `message` attribute.
Easy HTML code like:

```
<html>
   <head>
   ...
   </head
   <body>
     <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

[**----------Here is the image of project folder hierarchy----------**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5JMF.png)

Comment: can you post your project files structure? and the code for HelloPage?

Comment: @MosheArad I have just uploaded HTML base code that only displays attribute "message" in HelloPage.jsp. The image of the project structure is at the bottom of the article. Thanks

Comment: Try changing RequestMethod to GET in  RequestMapping

Comment: @JackFlamp It did not help either.